# Improve Inner-Join/Temp Table Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, inner-join, temp-tables

I have this query and it's returning the results I expect, however, as you can see it's really crude & difficult to read.

I tried Inner Joins and FIRST_VALUE approaches but wasn't getting the right results so resorted to temp tables (just because I find it easier to verify results that way).

The issue is I get a StartWayPoint and EndWayPoint from dbo.Trips which is actually just the first and last points entered into the GPSWaypoints table (for a particular trip / vehicle).

Those points aren't entered in UTCTime order so I need to take the StartWayPoint, EndWayPoint & Vehicle, get results BETWEEN those waypoint values from dbo.GPSWaypoints table, sort that by UTCTime desc and the first Location string there is my true EndLocationString.

Hope that makes sense, I may have over complicated it ....I feel as though the answer is either an Inner Join or a SubQuery, my SQL skills aren't that hot though so any help appreciated.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp1, #temp2

USE         XXX

DECLARE     @StartWayPoint bigint, @EndWaypoint bigint, @Vehicle smallint, @TripId smallint = 9863;

SELECT      t.Id, 
            t.Date, 
            t.StartWayPoint, 
            t.EndWayPoint, 
            t.Distance, 
            t.Alarms, 
            t.FuelConsumption, 
            t.Vehicle, 
            gpsStart.UtcTime as TripStart, 
            gpsEnd.UtcTime as TripEnd, 
            gpsStart.LocationString as StartLocationString, 
            gpsEnd.LocationString as EndLocationString
INTO        #temp1
FROM        dbo.Trips t 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.GPSWaypoints gpsStart on StartWaypoint = gpsStart.Id 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.GPSWaypoints gpsEnd on EndWaypoint = gpsEnd.Id 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.Operators o on Driver = o.Id 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.Vehicles v on t.Vehicle = v.Id 
WHERE       t.id = @TripId


SELECT      @StartWayPoint = (SELECT StartWaypoint FROM #temp1), @EndWaypoint = (SELECT EndWaypoint FROM #temp1), @Vehicle = (SELECT Vehicle FROM #temp1)

SELECT TOP 1 g.Id, 
            g.LocationString, 
            g.Vehicle
INTO        #temp2
FROM        dbo.GPSWaypoints g
WHERE       Id BETWEEN @StartWayPoint AND @EndWaypoint 
AND         Vehicle = @Vehicle 
order by    UtcTime desc

SELECT      t1.*,
            t2.Id as TRUE_EndWayPoint,
            t2.LocationString as TRUE_EndLocationString
FROM        #temp1 t1
LEFT JOIN   #temp2 t2 on t2.Vehicle = t1.
```

Results from #temp1

[image: Results from #temp1]

Results from #temp2 (with TRUE EndWayPoint and EndLocationString

[image: Results from #temp2 (with TRUE EndWayPoint and EndLocationString]

Answer (score 1):

Think I've answered it for myself with a nested query, must have just had an error in my earlier attempts ....still open to suggestions for improvement though.

```
select  t.Id, 
        t.Date, 
        t.StartWayPoint, 
        t.EndWayPoint, 
        t.Distance, 
        t.Alarms, 
        t.FuelConsumption,      
        t.Vehicle,          
        gpsStart.UtcTime as TripStart, 
        gpsEnd.UtcTime as TripEnd, 
        gpsStart.LocationString as StartLocationString, 
        (   select top 1 (g.LocationString) 
            from dbo.GPSWaypoints g 
            where Id BETWEEN gpsStart.Id AND gpsEnd.Id 
            AND Vehicle = v.Id 
            order by UtcTime desc
        ) as EndLocationString
from    dbo.Trips t 
left join dbo.GPSWaypoints gpsStart on StartWaypoint = gpsStart.Id 
left join dbo.GPSWaypoints gpsEnd on EndWaypoint = gpsEnd.Id 
left join dbo.Operators o on Driver = o.Id 
left join dbo.Vehicles v on t.Vehicle = v.Id 
where   t.id = 9863
```